# Link to subcategories by showing representative products

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, categories

On a category page, is it possible to show products (one or more) from **each sub-category** such that when one of those products is clicked, the user is directed to **the product's category page**, showing all products of that category?

It is just adding one step before category page.

Comment: Are you looking for specific categories or all "top level" categories on a given site? What type of page will this be included in: CMS (homepage), existing catalog page or a page from a custom module?

Comment: i want to design a page like this    http://www.garnstudio.com/lang/en/kategori_oversikt.php   in this when you will click on any product it will redirect you to its category page please look at this

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the [following extension](http://www.customy.com/magento-extensions/display-products-grouped-by-subcategories.html).
This extension allows you to display products grouped by subcategories in their parent category.